# PowerShell HtmlAgilityPack within class method

Tags: powershell, html-agility-pack

I use HtmlAgilityPack in my PowerShell script. As per the documentation my code is like:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("d:\Apl\HtmlAgilityPack.1.11.29\lib\Net40\HtmlAgilityPack.dll")
[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument]$htmlDoc = @{}
$htmlDoc.LoadHtml($resp.content)
...
```

This works fine as expected as long as I use simple script with functions only (no classes). Now I have refactored my code so that the `[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument]` type is used within a class method.

Now the compiler complains `"Unable to find type [HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument]."`. How do I load/import the type in order to be able to use it within a class method?

I use PowerShell 7.0 in Windows 10 environment.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution

```
Add-Type -path "d:\Apl\HtmlAgilityPack.1.11.29\lib\Net40\HtmlAgilityPack.dll"
$htmlDoc = New-Object HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
```